# Error: Opening COM: file not found - Nodejs, express, serialPort

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, node-serialport

I am trying to connect from nodejs to a fiscal printer that is connected by serial input and it gives me an error. I am using the serialPort module and I am following the steps in the documentation and it gives me the following error: "Error: Opening COM1: file not found".

I have already validated the port to which the printer is connected and if it is connected to the COM1 port, then I don't know what the error would be.

```
router.get('/printer', async (req, res) => {
   const serialPort = require("serialport")
    const port = new serialPort(
      'COM1',
      {baudRate: 9600,
      dataBits: 8,
      parity: 'mark',
      stopBits: 1},
   )
  const parser = new serialPort.parsers.Readline()
  port.pipe(parser)
  parser.on('data', (line) =>{
     console.log(line)
     port.write('0x02')
   })
})
```

Comment: I assume this is on Windows right?

Comment: Yes, in windows

Comment: If you're 100% sure it's connected to SOFTWARE COM1 (which may be different from hardware com1, eg. COM1 may be a USB device, COM2 may be a receipt printer, COM3 may be connected to the hardware com1 port etc.) then the problem may be your process don't have permission to access COM1. Try running your script as administrator